# 'jQuery is not defined' in Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, meteor

Seem to be getting a strange error after downloading semantic-ui and I can't get it to run when I've chosen what I do, and do not want in my custom.semantic.json file. I've tried also downloading/installing the jQuery package to my directory with no joy. Error message below.

```
>/Users/Kyle/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>     at app/definitions/behaviors/api.js:1081:5
>     at app/definitions/behaviors/api.js:1083:3
>     at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/portfolio/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Kyle/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>     at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/portfolio/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
> Exited with code: 8 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file
> change.
```

Comment: Meteor comes with jQuery. How did you install Semantic-UI? Did you use this package? https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui

Comment: Yep, I know it does, which is why I'm wondering why I'm getting this issue. I installed semantic-UI through command line into my Meteor directory and then created the custom.semantic.json file, as soon as it scaffolds out the app and creates the folders I start getting jQuery issues. Weird one! And yep, right from Atmosphere JS.

Comment: Well, looking at the docs under `Usage`: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor/ - it seems that you want to first create an *empty* `custom.semantic.json`, and only then do you start Meteor. After Meteor has started you can then edit `custom.semantic.json`.

Comment: I have done this, the file creates and then scaffolds out the rest of app, then I get that error. I have read the documentation umpteen times.

Comment: What displays when you do `meteor list`? Are you doing something like accidentally loading jQuery twice, the second time maybe being from code in your HTML? I just installed the Semantic-UI package and it starts right up.

Comment: I'm not at my computer at the moment but I tried this last night and jQuery was on the list once along with other dependences. I'm going to try installing it at my work machine in a few minutes and I'll comment on my outcome, could be something with my machine alone.

Comment: Got the same issue after changing a property in the custom.semantic.json file to get it scaffold the app on a different machine. Creates the relevant definitions/site/themes folders then asks where jQuery is.

Comment: What's in your `custom.semantic.json`?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny http://pastebin.ca/3068157

Comment: It works fine for me. What's `app/definitions/behaviors/api.js` ?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny related to semantic-ui. http://pastebin.ca/3068205

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Meteor, this happens when `custom.semantic.json` is inside the root's `lib/` folder. Thus, Semantic-UI generates all its folders and files in `lib/` which is loaded *before* any of its core dependencies, such as jQuery.

The solution is to place `custom.semantic.json` in an app folder, such as `client/lib/semantic-ui/`.